# Why does mysqli queries return false?

Tags: php, mysqli

The code below is supposed to allow you to view a list of friends
and edit or delete from the same page. The viewing works, but the deleting and updating does not. Any help would be appreciated.
 View code:

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM tblFriends";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        while($row =$result->fetch_assoc()){

        $fname=$row['fname'];
        $lname=$row['lname'];
        $address=$row['address'];
        $desc=$row['description'];
        $zip=$row['zip'];
        $city=$row['city'];
        $state=$row['state'];
        $id =$row['key'];

    echo 
    "<tr>
    <td><input type='text' name='fname' value='$fname'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='lname' value='$lname'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='address' value='$address'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='city' value='$city'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='desc' value='$desc'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='state' value='$state'/></td>
    <td><input type='submit' name='Edit' value='Edit'/></td>
    <td><input type='submit' name='Delete' value='Delete'/></td>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='zip' value='$zip'/>
    </tr>";
    }
```

Update Code:

```
        if(isset($_POST['Edit'])){
            $fname1=$_POST['fname'];
            $lname1=$_POST['lname'];
            $city1=$_POST['city'];
            $state1=$_POST['state'];
            $zip1=$_POST['zip'];
            $desc1=$_POST['desc'];
            $address1=$_POST['address'];
            $id1=$_POST['id'];
            $UpdateQuery ="UPDATE tblfriends SET fname='$fname1', lname='$lname1',city='$city1',address='$address1',zip='$zip1',state='$state1' WHERE id=$id1";
            echo $id1;
            if( mysqli_query($conn,$UpdateQuery)){
                echo "Updated";
            }else{
                echo "Not Updated";
            }

    }
```

Delete Code:
This `mysqli_query` and the update one both return false

```
if(isset($_POST['Delete'])){
            $id2 =$_POST['id'];
            $deleteQuery= "DELETE FROM tblfriends WHERE id=$id2";
            if( mysqli_query($conn,$deleteQuery)){
                echo "Deleted";
            }else{
                echo "Not Deleted";
            }
```

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? You should always check if you have errors on your queries.

Comment: @Andrius I did not know that there was error reporting , how would I know if it's on?

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` shoud help. Edit your question if you get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive looked throug your quesry lol, SPOT the odd one out?

```
$id =$row['key'];

"UPDATE tblfriends SET fname='$fname1', lname='$lname1',city='$city1',address='$address1',zip='$zip1',state='$state1' WHERE id=$id1

"DELETE FROM tblfriends WHERE id=$id2";
```

Just to help you out, your id name is key? but your checking if id matched id? Not sure but that might be your problem

So change your query to this

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM tblFriends";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    $fname=$row['fname'];
    $lname=$row['lname'];
    $address=$row['address'];
    $desc=$row['description'];
    $zip=$row['zip'];
    $city=$row['city'];
    $state=$row['state'];
    $id =$row['key'];

/**
**Wrapped your input into a form which will post the request
**/
    echo 
    "
    <form action=\"#\" method=\"POST\">
    <tr>
    <td><input type='text' name='fname' value='$fname'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='lname' value='$lname'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='address' value='$address'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='city' value='$city'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='desc' value='$desc'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='state' value='$state'/></td>
    <td><input type='submit' name='Edit' value='Edit'/></td>
    <td><input type='submit' name='Delete' value='Delete'/></td>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='zip' value='$zip'/>
    </tr>
    <br>
    </form>
    ";
};

if(isset($_POST['Edit'])){
    $fname1= $_POST['fname'];
    $lname1= $_POST['lname'];
    $city1= $_POST['city'];
    $state1= $_POST['state'];
    $zip1= $_POST['zip'];
    $desc1= $_POST['desc'];
    $address1= $_POST['address'];
    $id1= $_POST['id'];



/**
**Updated your query to match the key rather than ID. `key`
**/

    $UpdateQuery ="UPDATE tblfriends SET fname='$fname1', lname='$lname1',city='$city1',address='$address1',zip='$zip1',state='$state1' WHERE `key` = '$id1' ";
    echo $id1;
    if( mysqli_query($conn,$UpdateQuery)){
        echo "Updated";
    }else{
        echo "Not Updated";
    };

};

if(isset($_POST['Delete'])){
    $id2 = $_POST['id'];

/**
**Updated your query to match the key rather than ID. `key`
**/
    $deleteQuery= "DELETE FROM tblfriends WHERE `key` = '$id2' ";
    if( mysqli_query($conn,$deleteQuery)){
        echo "Deleted";
    }else{
        echo "Not Deleted";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this query `"DELETE FROM tblfriends WHERE id=$id2" with "DELETE FROM tblfriends WHERE id='$id2'"`. Better if you check your query by run it in query editor (like phpmyadmin in tab sql). 
Try testing like this in your code:

```
$deleteQuery= "DELETE FROM tblfriends WHERE id=$id2";
die($deleteQuery);
```

then copy the result that shown in browser, then paste in phpmyadmin. run it there. Hopefully it can help you